# iOS connecting to cellular network

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to figure out how to connect to a cellular network and what classes of iOS I should use?

And, does iOS 7 support apps checking data in the background? It would be similar to checking if you were in a certain location.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "connecting to a cellular network"? You don't do this in iOS. The hardware does this for you? What are you trying to do? I guess you need to get data from a web service or speak to Facebook or something similar? Am I correct?

Comment: Support of backround data acualization etc. is one of the new key featues of iOS7. What to you want to achieve? Do you want to initiate a call or connect to some IP service? There are dedicated APIs (and 3rd party framworks) around for those type of task.

Comment: If I have a device that runs on a 2g cellular network, how would I connect and send data to that device using my phone? I would want to periodically send it so background multitasking.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone will connect to a cellular network when you make any networking (internet) calls in your code. It will also connect to the internet through wifi, it doesn't care what type of connection you have, what you are trying to do is get info from the internet.

To do this, you must use some sort of networking library. The standard Apple-supported library is called NSURLSession and came out (an improvement upon the older NSURLConnection) with iOS7 and it works great. Suffer through the reading and you'll be rewarded - [Link to Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html)

There's also a 3rd party library called AFNetworking created by Mattt (yes, 3 t's) that's awesome and probably the most used 3rd party iOS library there is. Highly, highly recommend looking into this and giving some consideration when wanting to talk to the internet through an app. - [Link to AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com)